# Explanation of Cypress session behavior

Tags: cypress

I'm confused how Cypress is clearing the testing session to a blank page, and/or how `testIsolation:false` works. Cypress allows reusable test commands and sessions, like the one below:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('signin', (email, password) => {
  cy.session([email, password], () => {
    cy.visit('/'); // ???

    cy.get('[data-test=signin-input-email]').type(email);
    cy.get('[data-test=signin-input-password]').type(password);
    cy.get('[data-test=signin-submit]').click();

    // Assert successful login
    cy.get('[data-test=auth-card').contains(email);
  });
});
```

When using command/session like this in tests, there are some unexpected behavior. For example, the tests below error because "page was cleared by navigating to about:blank"; But why does it do when it was programmed to `cy.visit('/')`?

```js
describe('signin', () => {
  it('submits signin form with valid data', () => {
    cy.signin('valid.email@example.com', 'validpassword123');
    // Assert successful login
    cy.get('[data-test=auth-card').contains('Valid Email');
  });

  it('signs out', () => {
    cy.signin('valid.email@example.com', 'validpassword123');
    cy.get('[data-test=auth-menu]').click();
    cy.contains('Sign out').click();
    cy.get('[data-test=signin-input-email]').should('exist');
  });
});
```

Furthermore, if I modify the tests to use the `{ testIsolation: false }` option, the second test fails because the signin is not executed. How can I better write these commands or tests to get the expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Single `it` statement per test.
2. Don't call `cy.visit()` within `cy.session`'s callback.

Related: Prefer non-ui (API) login.

---

#### [Best Practices](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices) (Cypress.io):

> We've seen many users writing this kind of code:
>
> ```
> describe('my form', () => {   beforeEach(() => {
>     cy.visit('/users/new')
>     cy.get('[data-testid="first-name"]').type('johnny')   })
>
>   it('has validation attr', () => {
>     cy.get('[data-testid="first-name"]').should(
>       'have.attr',
>       'data-validation',
>       'required'
>     )   })
>
>   it('has active class', () => {
>     cy.get('[data-testid="first-name"]').should('have.class', 'active')   })
>
>   it('has formatted first name', () => {
>     cy.get('[data-testid="first-name"]')
>       // capitalized first letter
>       .should('have.value', 'Johnny')   }) })
> ```
>
> While technically this runs fine - this is really excessive, and not
> performant.
>
> Why you do this pattern in component and unit tests:
>
> When assertions failed you relied on the test's title to know what
> failed You were told that adding multiple assertions was bad and
> accepted this as truth There was no performance penalty splitting up
> multiple tests because they run really fast Why you shouldn't do this
> in end-to-end tests:
>
> Writing integration tests is not the same as unit tests You will
> always know (and can visually see) which assertion failed in a large
> test Cypress runs a series of async lifecycle events that reset state
> between tests Resetting tests is much slower than adding more
> assertions It is common for tests in Cypress to issue 30+ commands.
> Because nearly every command has an implicit assertion (and can
> therefore fail), even by limiting your assertions you're not saving
> yourself anything because any single command could implicitly fail.
>
> How you should rewrite those tests:
>
> ```
> describe('my form', () => {   beforeEach(() => {
>     cy.visit('/users/new')   })
>
>   it('validates and formats first name', () => {
>     cy.get('[data-testid="first-name"]')
>       .type('johnny')
>       .should('have.attr', 'data-validation', 'required')
>       .and('have.class', 'active')
>       .and('have.value', 'Johnny')   }) })
> ```

#### [Session](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session) (Cypress.io):

> Where to call cy.visit()
>
> Intuitively it seems that you should call cy.visit() immediately after
> cy.session() in your login function or custom command, so it behaves
> (from the point of view of the subsequent test) exactly the same as a
> login function without cy.session().
>
> ```
> const login = (name) => {   cy.session(name, () => {
>     cy.visit('/login')
>     cy.get('[data-test=name]').type(name)
>     cy.get('[data-test=password]').type('s3cr3t')
>     cy.get('#submit').click()
>     cy.url().should('contain', '/home')   })   cy.visit('/home') }
>
> beforeEach(() => {   login('user') })
>
> it('should test something on the /home page', () => {   // assertions })
>
> it('should test something else on the /home page', () => {   // assertions })
> ```
>
> However, if you want to test something on a different page, you will
> need to call cy.visit() at the beginning of that test, which means you
> will be calling cy.visit() a second time in your test. Since
> cy.visit() waits for the visited page to become active before
> continuing, this could add up to an unacceptable waste of time.
>
> ```
> // ...continued...
>
> it('should test something on the /other page', () => {   cy.visit('/other')   // assertions })
> ```
>
> Tests will obviously be faster if you call cy.visit() only when
> necessary. This can be easily realised by organizing tests into suites
> and calling cy.visit() after logging in, inside a beforeEach hook.
>
> ```
> const login = (name) => {   cy.session(name, () => {
>     cy.visit('/login')
>     cy.get('[data-test=name]').type(name)
>     cy.get('[data-test=password]').type('s3cr3t')
>     cy.get('#submit').click()
>     cy.url().should('contain', '/home')   })   // no visit here }
>
> describe('home page tests', () => {   beforeEach(() => {
>     login('user')
>     cy.visit('/home')   })
>
>   it('should test something on the /home page', () => {
>     // assertions   })
>
>   it('should test something else on the /home page', () => {
>     // assertions   }) })
>
> describe('other page tests', () => {   beforeEach(() => {
>     login('user')
>     cy.visit('/other')   })
>
>   it('should test something on the /other page', () => {
>     // assertions   }) })
> ```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the `cy.session()` only runs the setup callback (which is the code block containing `cy.visit()`) just the one time.

On the second call it just restores tokens from cache to cookies (or localstorage or session data).

So ***with test isolation on***

- first test

  1. calls `cy.session()`
  2. which calls the session setup function
  3. which calls `cy.visit()`
  4. navigates wherever `cy.get('[data-test=signin-submit]').click()` redirects
- second test

  1. navigates to `about/blank` to clear the whole page
  2. calls `cy.session()`
  3. session restores the cached credentials
  4. session ***does not call the session setup function***
  5. ***does not navigate anywhere***

So - in 2nd, 3rd, 4th tests you should navigate after calling `cy.session()`

---

The section [Where to call cy.visit()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session#Where-to-call-cyvisit) explains it -

```js
const login = (name) => {
  cy.session(name, () => {
    cy.visit('/login')
    cy.get('[data-test=name]').type(name)
    cy.get('[data-test=password]').type('s3cr3t')
    cy.get('#submit').click()
    cy.url().should('contain', '/home')
  })
  // no visit here
}

describe('home page tests', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    login('user')
    cy.visit('/home')      // navigating from "about/blank" to "/home"
  })
```